# alt key always pressed automatically

Tags: laptop, keyboard, asus-laptop

the errors:

- the alt key always pressed by itself ( it is not actually stuck and pressed).
- i need to hold super key to be able click any button or entering text box but sometimes i can't type at all. i am not sure if it is because system think i am pressing shortcut or all my keys also broken.

My laptop is: asus x455l

2 days ago i decided to disassemble the components and clean them up. it works for hours until midnight. and in the morning the alt button started acting strange again.

and yesterday i opened the case again and replace the glue (the black plastic) on the keyboard. and it worked for couple of hours maybe 13 hours until midnight, and now (morning) it is starting to error again (the alt key).

is there something i can do? i am okay if i can totally disable the alt button. of course fix it would be better.

Comment: Take your  laptop to a repair shop.

Comment: i am on limited budget, that is why i am here to find any possible way i can do. thanks for your useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you're comfortable with opening the laptop, you could insert a wedge of some sort, e.g. a toothpick, under the membrane to disable the bad key (if you have two <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys, this should cause no problem.
2. [Replacement keyboards for *some* Asus models are as little as US$13.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QBGN09A) There are also model-specific instructions, including videos. It helps to get a better answer if you state the model number of your laptop.
3. Unplug the internal keyboard and use an external USB keyboard. *Caveat:* it might be impossible to use BIOS on a particular model if it does not recognize the external keyboard before booting, so test before unplugging the internal one.

Comment: is there any way to disable the alt key via bios? is it possible to buy that black plastic ( i dont know its name) only? i just opened the chase again and clean that black screen using tissue 30 min ago and the errors are gone now (of course i bet it is just temporary). btw can i clean that black plastic or screen using water?

Comment: AFAIK, Device Manager cannot disable the internal keyboard, and I would guess not BIOS. BTW, it's "case"  or (less commonly) "chassis", not "chase". As for "black plastic", a picture might be helpful.

Comment: i will take picture of it when this laptop acting strange again. i tried to find the pict on the image in google but failed since i dont know its name. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't found a fix yet:

You can disable the alt key through the windows registry most likely (Requires care), unless disabling specific keys requires more of a software programming intelligence in order to do so. There are also programs that can do it for you and you can remap it to basically do something else or do nothing most likely.

I'd suggest finding a way to get it fixed or remapping it though. Those shortcuts for Alt + Control + Delete and Alt + Tab are very useful. Assuming you are using windows, in which case, most Asus computers do.

Answer (score 0):

What did I do to fix it?

I just replaced my keyboard.

But before doing it there were many other things I tried:

1. Searched original Windows 7 and tried to purchase(I was using), but not purchased due to insufficient balance in my account.
2. checked every software issue.
3. I had opened each and every parts of laptop and cleaned properly.
4. I purchased Anti Virus and installed.

After using antivirus it seemed good because it worked well but after 3-4 days it happened again.

I also heard about Linux. But when I had installed this it worked well for 6-8 days then again I faced same issue.

Finally, I feel if alt is repeatedly pressing automatically, I should try to remove keyboard cable and should use external Keyboard.

And I did.

And finally the problem has gone away and the keyboard is working properly.

I am using External Keyboard and removed laptop's keyboard and now I am not facing this issue any more.

Comment: You're essentially telling the OP to replace their keyboard, which is a hardware solution to a problem which may be software-based.

Comment: @Joseph the problem might well be software based, but it can also be hardware as well. Replacing defective hardware *is* a solution,

Comment: @Mokubai I'd argue that this answer is akin to suggesting getting a new laptop if its bootloader is corrupt. Technically correct, yes, but otherwise rather obvious and contributing little to the discussion.